# lock class/file to avoid multiple access

Tags: python, pyserial

Example:

test.py

```
class test_class(object):
    def display(self):
        print "Hello"
```

lock1.py

```
from test import test_class
from time import sleep
obj = test_class()
while True:
    obj.display()
    sleep(1)
```

lock2.py

```
from test import test_class
obj = test_class()
# Raise error if instance of test_class has been implemented before
try:
   obj.display()
except Exception as e:
   print e
```

What I need to do is lock (or anything) the class (or entire test.py) for file lock2.py if the object has already been initialized for that class
before raising Error(or Expeption). I've simplied the example though the example might not look relevant.

I tried locking the file i.e. test.py using

```
http://packages.python.org/lockfile/lockfile.html

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.lockfile
```

but it doesn't seem to help.

---

### HERE IS A ACTUAL CODE SNIPPET

comm_port.py

```
import serial
class CommPort(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0")
        # update in db (I've removed actual db update process
        # db.flag = 1
```

accessing_file1.py

```
from comm_port import CommPort
# if db.flag != 1:
    port = Commport()
    port.ser.flushInput()
    port.ser.flushOutput()
    ## will flush the buffer.. what if it flused the data that was supposed for go for accessing_file2
    port.ser.write("1")
    # do stuff using serial-port object "port"
    # lets say script gets busy for 30 secs for doing some stuffs
    # db.flag = 0
```

accessing_file2.py

```
from comm_port import CommPort
# if db.flag != 1:
    port = Commport()
    port.ser.flushInput()
    port.ser.flushOutput()
    port.ser.write("2")
    # do stuff using serial-port object "port"
    # lets say script gets busy for 40 secs for doing some stuffs
    # db.flag = 0
```

Still the example might not look relevant but this is my case.
Both of file can be activated at once too but I need only one to operate at a time.
what i did was created a db flag if comm_port.py is used and rest files check this flag. 
if comm_port is busy other accessing files will not work.
But I dont think its best practice.

So I need to check if there is a way to check if CommPort class is being instiated by any object or
by locking the comm_port.py or any other existing ideas are most welcome.

Comment: I can't read any of this. What are you asking, and what is the problem?

Comment: sorry for the formatting...I'm editing it.. :)

Comment: What do you mean by locking a file?  Are you referring to a class?  If it were a class, perhaps it could be done via the Singleton pattern, but I have to understand what your intent is before I go suggesting stuff.

Comment: Thanks Makoto.
I think the original code snippet will help. I'll post it

Comment: Are your multiple users, e.g. `lock1.py` and `lock2.py` separate applications, or are they simply separeate parts of the same application?

Comment: ok, the new edit isn't much of an explanation...

Comment: ya lock1.py and lock.py
OR
accessing_file1.py and accessing_file2.py

are different applications 
but import common file test.py OR comm_port.py
for similar type of purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply a lock to this situation, since importing doesn't work this way. An imported module is only executed **once**, the first time it is imported. Subsequent imports only copy the existing reference from `sys.modules`. You will need to figure out what your actual problem is and ask about that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if an instance already exists and raise an error if it does:

```
In [1]: import gc

In [2]: class Foo(object):
   ...:     pass

In [3]: bar=Foo()

In [4]: [item for item in gc.get_referrers(Foo) if isinstance(item,Foo)]
Out[4]: [<__main__.Foo at 0x187cc90>]
```

use `any([isinstance(item,Foo) for item in gc.get_referrers(Foo)])`, if True, raise an exeption.

Comment: It didn't helped. I think I'll work only in one file. But in my case I'm using different applications e.g. lock1.py and lock2.py separately
which uses e.g. common class Foo